# Kmeans with initial centroids give different outputs in Matlab and Python environment

Tags: python, matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

The input to the Kmeans in both the Matlab and Python environments is the following list:

```
input = [1.11, 0.81, 0.61, 0.62, 0.62, 1.03, 1.16, 0.44, 0.42, 0.73, 0.74, 0.65, 0.59, 0.64, 0.98, 0.89, 0.62, 0.95, 0.88, 0.60, 0.61, 0.62, 0.62, 0.64, 0.98, 0.90, 0.64]
```

**Matlab:**

```
[idx, C] = kmeans(input',3,'Start',[0.3;0.9;1.5]);
```

**Output**

```
C = [0.596, 0.825, 1.035]

(idx==1) = 15, (idx==2) = 6, (idx==3) = 6
```

**Python:**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, n_init=1, init=np.array([0.3,0.9,1.5]).reshape(-1,1)).fit(np.array(input).reshape(-1, 1))
idx = kmeans.labels_
C = kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

**Output**

```
C = [0.430, 0.969, 0.637]

(idx==0) = 2, (idx==1) = 10, (idx==2) = 15
```

Clearly, the output centroids and the number of input points classified in the 3 clusters are different for these environments. What is the reason behind this even when the initial centroids are the same?

Comment: It's most likely due to difference in implementation. According to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58238/how-random-are-the-results-of-the-kmeans-algorithm) there are several common ways to implement it,

Comment: In the post you mentioned, it is stated that: "K-means is only randomized in its starting centers. Once the initial candidate centers are determined, it is deterministic after that point." Since I am already providing the initial centroid positions, Kmeans should only run once and produce the same centroid outputs. I am assuming that randomization only happens in choosing the initial centroids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've writed a minimal kmeans algorithm to test your dataset with matlab:

```matlab
input = [1.11, 0.81, 0.61, 0.62, 0.62, 1.03, 1.16, 0.44, 0.42, 0.73, 0.74, 0.65, 0.59, 
         0.64, 0.98, 0.89, 0.62, 0.95, 0.88, 0.60, 0.61, 0.62, 0.62, 0.64, 0.98, 0.90, 
         0.64];

c     = [0.3;0.9;1.5]

for ii = 1:10
    [~,idx] = min(abs(c-input));         % pairwise euclidian distance
    c = accumarray(idx.',input,[],@mean) % compute the new centroid
end
```

After the first iteration the index `idx`, that indicate which is the closest centroid for each value, looks like this:

```
 2   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   2...
```

The last centroid (`1.5` here) is NEVER the closest value ! So in order to keep 3 groups the `kmeans` algorithm have to compute, somehow, a new value for this centroid (because it's hard to compute the mean of an empty set). And it looks like python and matlab have different implementation for it.

If you want to avoid this problem make sure that every initial centroid is the closest value for, at least, one element of your dataset.

You can, for example, take the first three differents value of your dataset.

Comment: Thank you @obchardon for this clarification. You are absolutely right that the third centroid is never chosen. I tried the initial centroids as: C = [min(input);(min(input)+max(input))/2;max(input)]; and in fact the output centroids were same in both the Matlab and Python environments.